# Get the First day and the last day of month from an Instant

Tags: java, validation, date

I have a method using 2 Instants in parameters `getIssuesBillable(Instant start, Instant end, ....)`, my question is how I get the first day of a month and the last day of the month using a Java 8 Instant? 
I already tried use **`withDayOfMonth()`**, and **`lengthOfMonth()`**:

```
LocalDate initial = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate start = initial.withDayOfMonth(firstDayOfMonth());
LocalDate end = initial.withDayOfMonth(lastDayOfMonth());
```

But in this case, I need to convert and make some workarounds in this case, if someone knows a better way to do it I really appreciate any response.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use modern *java.time* classes.

Here is a brief nonsensical example of starting with an `Instant` (a moment in UTC), assigning a time zone to view that moment through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), extracting the year-and-month as perceived in that time zone, and determining the first and last day of that month, rendering `LocalDate` objects.

```
YearMonth                                 // Represent a year-and-month, the entire month as a whole.
.from(                                    // Determine the year-and-month of some other date-time object.
    Instant                               // Represent a moment in UTC.
    .now()                                // Capture the current moment in UTC.
    .atZone(                              // Adjust from UTC to a particular time zone.
        ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) 
    )                                     // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
)                                         // Returns a `YearMonth` object.
.atDay( 1 )                               // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
```

…or

```
…
.atEndOfMonth()                           // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
```

By the way, a realistic version of that particular code would be: `YearMonth.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ).atDay( 1 )`

## Moment versus date-only

[`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), a date with time-of-day and an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero.

A [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) is a date-only value, without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone).

You need to specify the time zone by which you want to perceive the date, the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract the date-only.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

From there, proceed with your other code.

Or work with the month as a whole, using [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from( zdt ) ;
LocalDate first = ym.atDay( 1 ) ;
LocalDate last = ym.atEndOfMonth() ;
```

Tip: You might find helpful the [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) and [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) classes in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library.

Tip: Learn about the Half-Open approach to define a span of time, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So a month starts on the first and runs up to, but does not include, the first day of the *following* month.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

For the first day of the month, depends on the time zone:

```
YearMonth.from(Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))).atDay(1);
```

For the last day of the month, depends on the time zone:

```
YearMonth.from(Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))).atEndOfMonth();
```

Comment: It’s already in the other answer. Nice to have the short version too.

Comment: ty for sharing at a short version